# How to compare unordered elements to another unordered list?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have this code

```
game = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
solution_sets = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(7,5,3)]

class PlayerX():
    listX = []
class PlayerO():
    listO = []

X = PlayerX()
O = PlayerO()
winner = 0

while (winner == 0):
    inputX = input()
    inputX = int(inputX)
    X.listX.append(inputX)
    inputO = input()
    inputO = int(inputO)
    O.listO.append(inputO)

    if any(item in X.listX for item in solution_sets):
        winner = 1
        print("Player X is the winner")
        break

    elif any(item in O.listO for item in solution_sets):
        winner = 1
        print("Player O is the winner")
        break

    else:
        print(X.listX)
        print(O.listO)
```

It's meant to be the logic for a 3 by 3 tic-tac-toe board, I just used the numbers 1-9 to represent the squares. The solution set consists of all possible ways to win. I need to compare the lists listX and listO to the elements in the solution set, there is no need for elements to be in the same order as those in the solution set.

When I run this code the checking is not correct as the listX could be [9,7,8] and would not be evaluated as a solution. What options do I have for data structures and how do I implement this code properly?

Comment: And, I guess that listX could also be `[1,9,7,8]`. That is still a winning position, am I wrong? If not, you should specify it in your question, because then, we are not just trying to find ordered listX among solution_set. We are trying to find if one of the elements of solution set is entirely included in listX.

Answer (score 0):

### One-liner

One one-liner, using sets.

```py
solution_sets = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(7,5,3)]

def winning(lst):
    return any(set(x).issubset(lst) for x in solution_sets)
```

```
>>> winning([1,2,3])
True
>>> winning([1,2,4])
False
>>> winning([3,2,1])
True
>>> winning([3,5,2,1])
True
>>> winning([3,5,4,1])
False
>>> winning([3,5,4,3,1])
False
>>> winning([9,8,7])
True
>>> winning([9,8,3,7])
True
```

Or, a faster version, replacing solution_sets by an actual list of sets (to avoid converting them each time.

```
solution_sets=[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 9, 7}, {1, 4, 7}, {8, 2, 5}, {9, 3, 6}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}]
def winning(lst):
    return any(x.issubset(lst) for x in solution_sets)
```

The main trick here is to check if intersection of two sets contains 3 members. Because they are sets, order and redundancy do not matter. And it is supposed to be as efficient as possible, since the `O(n.log(n))` computation (not `O(n²)` I am pretty sure: sets are probably sorted, so `O(n.log(n))`, and then compared using a `O(n)` algorithm, comparing the lowest value of each set each time), or let say, putting aside this big-O considerations, the matching of listX and solution is done in internal python code, which is always more efficient than if we had done loops ourselves.

Or even better, use sets all the way in your code

```py
class PlayerX():
    setX = {}
# (...)
while (winner == 0):
    inputX = input()
    inputX = int(inputX)
    X.setX.add(inputX)
# (...)
```

It doesn't change `winning` code. But it becomes faster, because this avoid the implicit conversion of tuple to set that is done each time by `x.issubset(lst)` when lst is a tuple.

### "in" based solution

I don't think there could be a `in` based solutions, unless you create a huge list of all possible winning combination (and there are lot of them, since winning combinations are not just the "winning in 3 steps" combinations. 12960, not just the 48 of Talha's solution. Far less, but still 154, ignoring the order. Which you can do simply by listing sets instead of tuples).
Plus, I don't see any way to compute those winning solutions than using another method (like my previous one).

But, well, just for the sake of exploring how we would do it, if we wanted absolutely to do it that way, let's generate the solution_sets using my first method. And then forget the 1st function, and write another function based on this set.

### Generating code

I start with some experiments to discover itertools and how it can help

```py
import itertools

# We use combinations to create all possible combinations of [1,2,...9] (ignoring order, that is what are "combinations"), of length 3, 4 or 5 (there can't be a winning solution with less than 3 numbers. Nor can't there be a non-cheating winning solution with more than 5)
# Print all possible 3 steps
for c in itertools.combinations(range(1,10),3):
    print(c)
# prints (1,2,3), (1,2,4), ..., (7,8,9)
# Print all possible 4 steps
for c in itertools.combinations(range(1,10),4):
    print(c)
# prints (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,5), ..., (6,7,8,9)
# Print all possible 5 steps
for c in itertools.combinations(range(1,10),5):
    print(c)
# prints (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,4,6), ..., (5,6,7,8,9)

# In fact, we can do this in a single loop, that is a single iterator, chaining the 3 previous
for c in itertools.chain(itertools.combinations(range(1,10),3), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),4), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),5)):
    print(c)
# prints (1,2,3), (1,2,4), ..., (5,6,7,8,9)

# The compound list version, build a list of all combinations of 3, 4, 5 steps
[c for c in itertools.chain(itertools.combinations(range(1,10),3), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),4), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),5))]
# [(1,2,3), (1,2,4), ..., (5,6,7,8,9)]

# We can have sets instead of tuples
[set(c) for c in itertools.chain(itertools.combinations(range(1,10),3), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),4), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),5))]
# [{1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, ..., {5,6,7,8,9}]

# And more importantly, we can keep winning solutions, filtering using my first solution
[set(c) for c in itertools.chain(itertools.combinations(range(1,10),3), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),4), itertools.combinations(range(1,10),5)) if winning(c)]
# [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 7}, ...,  {4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}]
# That is what we must copy and paste to create our second "winning" version
```

So now that we have done that, we can erase our previous winning solution. We have used it, somehow, to "compile" an explicit list of all winning solutions. And use this list in this second version, closer to the one you were trying to build

### Generated code

```py
solution_sets2 = [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 5, 9}, 
      {8, 2, 5}, {3, 5, 7}, {9, 3, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, 
      {8, 9, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, 
      {1, 2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 7}, {8, 1, 2, 3}, 
      {1, 2, 3, 9}, {1, 2, 4, 7}, {8, 1, 2, 5}, 
      {1, 2, 5, 9}, {1, 3, 4, 7}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, 
      {1, 3, 5, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 9}, {1, 4, 5, 6}, 
      {1, 4, 5, 7}, {1, 4, 5, 9}, {1, 4, 6, 7}, 
      {8, 1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 9, 7}, {1, 5, 6, 9}, 
      {1, 5, 9, 7}, {8, 1, 5, 9}, {8, 1, 9, 7}, 
      {2, 3, 5, 7}, {8, 2, 3, 5}, {9, 2, 3, 6}, 
      {2, 4, 5, 6}, {8, 2, 4, 5}, {8, 2, 5, 6}, 
      {8, 2, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 2, 5}, {8, 9, 2, 7}, 
      {3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 7}, {9, 3, 4, 6}, 
      {3, 5, 6, 7}, {9, 3, 5, 6}, {8, 3, 5, 7}, 
      {9, 3, 5, 7}, {9, 3, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 3, 6}, 
      {8, 9, 3, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 4, 5, 6}, 
      {9, 4, 5, 6}, {8, 9, 4, 7}, {8, 9, 5, 7}, 
      {8, 9, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6},
      {1, 2, 3, 4, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 
      {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, 
      {1, 2, 3, 5, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 8}, 
      {1, 2, 3, 6, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 7, 9}, 
      {1, 2, 3, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 7}, 
      {1, 2, 4, 5, 8}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 9}, {1, 2, 4, 6, 7}, 
      {1, 2, 4, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 4, 7, 9}, {1, 2, 5, 6, 8}, 
      {1, 2, 5, 6, 9}, {1, 2, 5, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 5, 7, 9}, 
      {1, 2, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
      {1, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 9}, {1, 3, 4, 6, 7}, 
      {1, 3, 4, 6, 9}, {1, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, 
      {1, 3, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 3, 5, 6, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 8}, 
      {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 9}, 
      {1, 3, 6, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 
      {1, 4, 5, 6, 8}, {1, 4, 5, 6, 9}, {1, 4, 5, 7, 8}, 
      {1, 4, 5, 7, 9}, {1, 4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 6, 7, 8}, 
      {1, 4, 6, 7, 9}, {1, 4, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 5, 6, 7, 9}, 
      {1, 5, 6, 8, 9}, {1, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
      {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 8}, 
      {2, 3, 4, 6, 9}, {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 5, 6, 8}, 
      {2, 3, 5, 6, 9}, {2, 3, 5, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 5, 7, 9}, 
      {2, 3, 5, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 6, 7, 9}, {2, 3, 6, 8, 9}, 
      {2, 3, 7, 8, 9}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 8}, 
      {2, 4, 5, 6, 9}, {2, 4, 5, 7, 8}, {2, 4, 5, 8, 9}, 
      {2, 4, 7, 8, 9}, {2, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {2, 5, 6, 8, 9}, 
      {2, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {2, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 
      {3, 4, 5, 6, 8}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 7, 8}, 
      {3, 4, 5, 7, 9}, {3, 4, 6, 7, 9}, {3, 4, 6, 8, 9}, 
      {3, 4, 7, 8, 9}, {3, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 5, 6, 7, 9}, 
      {3, 5, 6, 8, 9}, {3, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {3, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
      {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 9}, {4, 5, 6, 8, 9}, 
      {4, 5, 7, 8, 9}, {4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}]

def winning2(lst):
    return set(lst) in solution_sets2
# or return lst in solution_sets2 
# if you have converted your code into using sets instead of list, as previously discussed
```

Note that I am not at all suggesting this solution. On the contrary. I show it to discourage it, to show what it would take to use this approach, and how long is the "solution set" (and it would be 100 times longer without using sets instead of tuples)

It could be a necessary wrong if it were faster (sacrifice code lisibility and memory usage, in favor of cpu time). But it is not. Both method use the same amount of cpu time (2.6 μs per computation on my computer. Slightly faster for the first version than the "generated" one)

Comment: Oh, so while it is possible to use the current method of determining solutions to tic-tac-toe it is not advisable I continue doing it the way I am currently doing it? Is that what you mean when discouraging the  "in" based solution? Also is there a way to model solutions in tic-tac-toe using matrices in python while not having to generate solution sets that will take up a lot of space?

Comment: You can do it with in, like I did with my second version. For tic-tac-toe it won't kill your computer. Those winning combinations list are not that much memory. Even the version with unordered tuples (that I did not post, cause I cannot copy&paste 12960 lines) uses "only" 12960 tuples. That is not a lot for a modern computer. A few megabytes at most, when memory is counted in gigabytes. Just, it is not really faster. And it would work only for 3×3 tic-tac-toe. You couldn't use the same technique for any other game, nor even for a 5×5 tic-tac-toe.

Comment: As for, _"a way to model solutions in tic-tac-toe using matrices in python while not having to generate solution sets"_: isn't it what my first solution is?